# Getting Notice: Undefined Index: id

Tags: php

I'm making a forum software right now, just for some practice, and I'm getting this error when displaying the forums of the site.

This is my current start to it. It works, it just gives me this error:

Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\forums.php on line 15

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");
mysql_select_db("forums");

$find = "SELECT ID,name,description FROM forums";  
$run_find = mysql_query("$find");
while($is = mysql_fetch_assoc ($run_find)) 
{
$id = $is['id'];
$name = $is['name'];
$des = $is['description'];

print "Forum : <a href='topics.php?t=$id'>". $name . "</a><br/>" .$des . "";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should change your key to:

```
$id = $is['ID'];
```

Comment: Common mistake=) You should try using var_dump or print_r when you get these kind of problems, displaying the keys and content of the array often helps.